# Disable redirects in spring-webflow

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm trying to use Spring WebFlow to build voice application - eg. application which produces VoiceXML and is interpreted by voice browser. There is no such concept as *back button* in the voice application and the redirects are therefore useless and only confuse the voice browser.

I have tried the `?mode=embedded`, but that has no effect. From what I understand this might suppress redirects for Ajax requests made within same view-state, but not redirects on transitions between states.

Is there any way to **completely** disable all redirects in spring-webflow?

Aleš